# Autofac register IHttpContextAccessor

Tags: asp.net-core, autofac

I use autofac PropertiesAutowired approach (ASP.NET CORE).
What I need is to get current user in class library project. How can I do it? I want something like this

```
public IHttpContextAccessor ContextAccessor{ get; set; }
```

and then to use it like

```
Context.HttpContext.User.Claims.First(i => i.Type == "NameIdentifier"
```

Is it possible to do or should I use something else for it?

Comment: You need to make sure the `IHttpContextAccessor` is registered. This isn't done automatically. Best is to refrain from using property injection, but use constructor injection instead, as `IHttpContextAccessor` seems to be a *mandatory* dependency. To register it, just call `services.AddHttpContextAccessor()`.

Comment: @Steven I do not think that using different DI and approaches is good idea.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "using different DI and approaches"?

Comment: @Steven We use autofac for DI, not build in microsoft container, so it seems for me it will be a mess to use. And as for approaches - there are autoproperty injection instead of via constructor. So, it will be not good to use in same class several autoproperty injection and ctor injection

Comment: Autofac *replaces* the built-in container, so even if you call `services.AddSomething, you will be adding it to Autofac. Apart from that, with ASP.NET Core, you *need* to add the `IHttpContextAccessor` to the framework-used container (most likely using `AddHttpContextAccessor()`). If you don't, its `HttpContext` property will *never* be set.

Comment: Whether or not Autofac supports property injection is irrelevant to following best practices. Best practice is to only make use of property injection in the rarest of cases. Property injection should only be used for dependencies that are truly optional; all other dependencies should be injected using constructor injection. It is valid to mix constructor injection and property injection in the same class. Please consult chapter 4.4 from [Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://manning.com/seemann2) to learn about best practices concerning property injection.

Comment: @Steven thank you for your answer and link. I really appreciate it

Comment: @Steven it's not required to use built in container for registering these classes.

Comment: @alsami: I never said it was.

Answer (score 5):

**Note:** Below only works when registering Autofac with ASP.NET Core as described [here](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#quick-start-with-configurecontainer) or [here](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#quick-start-without-configurecontainer).

If it is not required to use auto-wiring for properties I'd suggest you do the following

First, register the dependency as [singleton](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/7ca234607a37c9e7db06013a21208769e3eeb0a2/src/Http/Http/src/HttpServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L22) (yes, it's not a problem, MS does it too)

```
builder.RegisterType<HttpContextAccessor>()
   .As<IHttpContextAccessor>()
   .SingleInstance();
```

Assuming your class is called `MyClass` inject it via constructor

```
public MyClass(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
   ContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}
```

Now you are good to go! I am sure you can make it work with property-auto-wiring but I am not familiar with that approach.

As a side-note:

If you want to retrieve the information of the authenticated user, I heard and have read that it is recommended to write something like an `ApplicationUser` class that wraps the underlying framework logic.

I implemented something similar [here](https://github.com/alsami/Etdb.ServiceBase.AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Etdb.ServiceBase.Services/ApplicationUser.cs) that also uses `IHttpContextAccessor` to retrieve required claims + I am registering the accessor with autofac as well. Only difference is that I am using constructor-injection.

I hope that helps you!